# Angular 13, Chart.js, ng2-chart Update data from API dynamically

Tags: angular, chart.js, ng2-charts

I'm trying to dynamically update chart data from API. I'm using angular 13 and chart.Js 3.7.1.

I didn't found any straightforward example from their documentation.

I found [this](https://github.com/desoga10/angular-chart) example on web as well, Still that is not working here. Is there any clear example/tutorial?

Answer (score 1):

Being able to update the data of a chart is an essential task, so both Chart.js and ng2-charts (which is basically an Angular wrapper of Chart.js) have posted explicit examples:

- [Updating data on Chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/updates.html)

  ```
  function addData(chart, label, data) {
      chart.data.labels.push(label);
      chart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
          dataset.data.push(data);
      });
      chart.update();
  }
  ```
- [Updating data on ng2-charts](https://valor-software.com/ng2-charts/#LineChart) (check, for instance, the `randomize()` function)

  ```
  public randomize(): void {
      for (let i = 0; i < this.lineChartData.datasets.length; i++) {
          for (let j = 0; j < this.lineChartData.datasets[i].data.length; j++) {
              this.lineChartData.datasets[i].data[j] = LineChartComponent.generateNumber(i);
          }
      }
      this.chart?.update();
  }
  ```

On both cases, to update the data you will need to modify the `data` array. Keep in mind, you must explicitly call the `update()` function right after data update.

Answer (score 0):

It’s actually not immediately obvious how to do this from the ng2-chart documentation. I’m using Angular too so I can give you the steps to get that going.

My assumption is that you have the ng2chart package installed and loaded in your module and you want to show a Line chart. Amend the example to suit the chart type.
The data being retrieved from the API call is just the pure datasets array. This is merged with static axis labels and options data processed client side.

To update the chart dynamically (from an API call for instance) you’ll need a reference to the chart object in your HTML template.

Use the @Viewchild decorator to get a reference to your loaded chart.

```
@ViewChild(BaseChartDirective) chart?: BaseChartDirective;
```

Define three chart objects to configure the chart.

```
  lineChartType: ChartType = 'line';
  lineChartData: ChartConfiguration['data'];
  options: ChartConfiguration['options'] = {
    responsive: false
  };
```

This corresponds to your HTML template markup

```
<canvas baseChart width="800" height="600"
  [type]="lineChartType"
  [data]="lineChartData"
  [options]="options">
</canvas>
```

On your callback from your HTTP call (or however you retrieve the data), create an anonymous ‘datasets’ object.
NOTE  I tried strongly typing the object, however I noticed that missing properties (like backgroundColor) are dynamically loaded if not present & the class generics was working against me at this point.

```
  const datasets: any[] = [];

  ChartDataArrayFromYourAPICall.forEach((element:any) => {
    datasets.push({
      label: element.label,
      data: element.data,
    })
  });
```

Next, you need to update the bound property with your new dataset.

```
  this.lineChartData = {
    labels: CHARTMONTHSOFYEAR,
    datasets 
  };
```

And finally call the update method from your chart reference.

```
this.chart?.update();
```

That’s it.